# SSRS 2012 Show Null Values in Subreport

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services

I have an ssrs 2012 report that goes against and oracle database. I have a bar chart that gives a count of different late reasons for orders. When you click on one of the bars for a certain reason then it goes to a subreport that gives a table of details for all the orders with those reasons. Some of the late reasons are null and show up as an unlabeled bar on the bar chart. The users would like to be able to click on these to see what they are.

How do I need to have my sub report action expression, sub report parameter settings, and subreport query to accomplish this? In Oracle you use bind variables for SSRS instead of the @ symbol, so the sub report query is something like this just to give and example.

select * from orders
where 
Late_Reasons = :late_reason

Comment: Have you tried changing the query to include null records, i.e. select * from orders where NVL(Late_Reasons, 'X') = NVL(:late_reason, 'X')

Comment: Thanks man that did it! I made the parameter settings to "allow null value" and then changed it to how you said and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query to include null records

```
select * from orders where NVL(Late_Reasons, 'X') = NVL(:late_reason, 'X')
```